# Codeigniter 3 Routing Issues

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have setup a route in the routes.php file like this:

`$route['videos/video'] = 'videos';`

So if a user enters:

`http://domain.com/videos/video/`

I want it to just load the videos page which works, but the issue I am running into is that it is keeping the URL the same so when the user clicks on one of the videos from the videos page the url will look like this:

`http://domain.com/videos/video/video/1`

When is should look like this:

`http://domain.com/videos/video/1`

Is there any way to change this behavior?

Also, is there any way to hide the method in the URL?

Comment: I think that your problem is more related to the link href value that you are generating for each video. do you have the html code?

Comment: Here is the html link - `<a href="video/<?=$video->id?>"><?=$video->video_title?></a>` but if i remove `video/` it mess other pages up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$route['videos/video'] = "videos/index";
$route['videos/video/(:num)'] = "videos/video/$1";
```

Comment: I did what you showed in your answer but i also had to remove `video/` and add `$route['(:num)'] = 'videos/video/$1'` and `$route['videos/(:num)'] = 'videos/video/$1'` i will mark your answer correct.

Comment: In comment you are allowing same result from two links. It is not good for SEO.